# Redmon starts application as user SYSTEM instead of the current user

Tags: windows, spooler, redmon

I'm using Redmon to start a .Net application that reads data from stdin, then send it to ghostscript to generate a .pdf file, before wrapping everything in a .zip file, which is uploaded to an ftp server.

The problem is, that under some Windows implementations, particularly Windows 10 Pro, the started process will run as user SYSTEM instead of the current user. However, it doesn't seem to be the case every time. I have seen it running nicely on a pc for several weeks, and suddenly something must have changed, because the process began to run as SYSTEM, which makes my application fail because of missing registry entries and user-specific config files.

In Redmon, there is a setting called "run as user", which is enabled, but it doesn't really change anything. The documentation states that "this may or may not work".

I thought of letting the application fork a new process as the currently logged-in user, as suggested by others, but I only know how to do this by supplying a username and the user's password, which I don't have. I don't want to ask the user to enter his credentials.

So basically, I need to know *why* Redmon (or the Windows spooler) changes to the SYSTEM user on some systems, if this is a Windows setting, and if there is a way to avoid this. Alternatively, if I at least could have the SYSTEM process interact with the desktop, it would also be a step in the right direction.

Comment: I am facing same issue, please help me if you got solution

Comment: I found no good way to avoid this. I ended up with a solution where a background process is initiated at startup. When printing, Redmon saves the job to a .ps file queue that is then handled by the process running as the local user. Not neat, but it gets the job done.